# How is the keypair for every contract generated?

Tags: keypair, smart-contract

When we build a smart contract e.g., [program-examples/basics/hello-solana](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/hello-solana/native/program) there are two files in the `target/so` directory

```
hello_solana_program-keypair.json hello_solana_program.so
```

How is the hello_solana_program-keypair.json created? Is there a command I can use to recreate this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keypair is randomly generated by just using `Keypair::new()` if `program-name-keypair.json` isn't found in `target/deploy`.

If you've lost it, you can't recreate the old one, but you can generate a new one using:

```
solana-keygen new -o hello_solana_program-keypair.json
```

Source code which generates the keypair can be found at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/e70ff38f350a70528f9fefa3721427589844d3ae/sdk/cargo-build-sbf/src/main.rs#L766